# local autocomplete using jQuery-Autocomplete and mockjax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete
found this tutorial and was able to run it implement it on my app.my problem is, it wont run on local computer/app i think the problem is with mockjax is there way to make this tutorial run locally?or is there other way to make an autocomplete locally?this example is about autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In the config lookup is for local data that doesn't rely on external requests. This would rely on loading in the data through JS on the client.

If you want to run it locally why not boot up a simple http server with python and make a get request to a local file?

See here line 133: https://github.com/michaelBenin/Airport-Distance-Calculator/blob/master/script.js

Comment: i know your idea work but problem is i'm a new programmer i want a simple round about on this problem. plus im using html and jquery on this because these are the only one i know as of now.

this one? lookup: App.model.read(),  what to do with this?

Comment: So for lookup, just use a local array: ['blue', 'red', 'green']

Comment: ok..but i was thinking if there is a way to make this run with a text file so if the user type in something that is now on the list it will be automatically saved on the text file.is this even feasible?

Comment: That is feasible but you will need to make a $.get('my.txt') for that you will need a server running. Sounds like you don't have one. I would look into this http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python - or just use a js file that references a global variable thats an array of items, then you wouldn't need to run the server and just reference that variable. I hope this helps.

Comment: this will help others i think ive seen it cant understand python though